# Build user interface around API

Tags: python, html, post, curl

I have an app running in `Python` using `Flask`.

The endpoint of the `API` looks like this:

```
@app.route('/postIt', methods =['POST'])
def postReview():
    #print flask.request
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        posts  = flask.request.get_json()
        print posts
    return str(posts)
```

I am trying to send it request using `CURL`:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/postIt -d @post.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

where `post.json` looks like this:

```
{"post1":"3", "post2": "2", "post3":"3", "post4":"4" "post5": "5"}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I build a simple `HTML form` with 5 boxes labelled post1, post2, post3, post4, post5 and ask the user to post values into it which I can then send to my Python API same was as I am doing above with CURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery formulate a json POST request

```
<form id="form1" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/postIt"> 
  <input name="post1" value="3">
  <input name="post2" value="2">
  <input name="post3" value="3">
  <input name="post4" value="4">
  <input name="post5" value="5">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script>
  $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: JSON.stringify(form.data())
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. How can i view it in my browser? Will I not need any sort of html around it?

Comment: I fixed my answer. it should be `.done()` not `.success()`. That will print out to the console the response that the backend sends back

Comment: It seems like this method is converting request to `GET`. Here is the log: `127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2015 22:38:35] "GET /user-review?post1=3&post2=2&post3=3&post4=4&post5=5 HTTP/1.1" 405 - ` . How can I fix this issue?